# Screen reader omits disabled attribute

Tags: javascript, input, material-ui, screen-readers, disabled-input

I have a stepper - material UI number field. It is disabled but the screen reader is able to change the number (increment and decrement). HTML is as follows:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" id="outlined-number" type="number" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" disabled="true" value="3">
```

Comment: There is a good chance it is an issue with the screen reader if your code works in other places. It sounds like the screen reader isn't respecting the disabled tag. Do you have other screen readers to test with? Also, what is the specific screen reader?

Comment: Did you ever find what was causing the issue @AysunSulunTas?

Answer (score 4):

The `disabled` attribute is being specified wrong. From https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes:

> 2.4.2 Boolean attributes
>
> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

Change the code to `disabled="disabled"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried disabled="disabled" but the screen reader still is able to change the field although the area is disabled.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know then. As another comment said, the issue may be with a buggy screenreader.